# Strech a Image to full size as a background image

Tags: html, css

Been Trying to set an image fully stretched(such that it covers the entire page) as a background for a section. And what is the difference between background size: cover and 100% 100%

```
<section class="starter"></section>

.starter
{
background-image:url("C:/Users/Rakesh/Desktop/Medium v1.3/Section.jpg");
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
height: 100%;
width: 100px; 
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Here is a nice explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654996/what-is-the-difference-between-background-size-cover-and-background-size-100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background-size:100% 100%
```

causes the image to stretch and fill

---

```
background-size:cover
```

causes the image to maintain aspect ratio and crop

---

http://jsfiddle.net/pkrf1b5f/

Comment: What's the issue with my code i tried using background-size: cover but still it aint working

Comment: Your issue is your height is set to 100%. That will only work if your html and body tags have height:100% set. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/pkrf1b5f/2/

Comment: Thank you so much, can i know why so ?

Comment: Assuming the element is positioned relatively then height:100% will only work if the parent element has a fixed height (like 100px). If not then every parent element up to the html / body tag must have height:100%

Answer (score 0):

See this post:
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

```
html { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my code isnt working, maybe i couldnt get the concept or where am i doing it wrong