# Weird picture resolution in CSS

Tags: php, jquery, css, image, youtube

Just want the image to be the background, Fix where appropriate. Thankyou!

EDIT:

```
div {
color: #13eee6;
font: 30px Roboto;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

}

PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '1',
      width: '1',
      //videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      playerVars: 
      {
        listType:'playlist',
        list: 'PLsVV8G4dmXyE2mSm3ZSz_AcNVduhw2ZwM'
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,

      }
    });
  }

 // console.log(player);



  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();

    $('.title').text(event.target.getVideoData().title);

  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
    console.log(event);
     if ((event.data == -1)) {
        $('.title').text(event.target.getVideoData().title);
     }
  }     


  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>

<div class="title"> </div> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/z6fgaW8.png");
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div {
    color: #13eee6;
    font: 30px Roboto;
}
```

The Website: http://darklegionrp.byethost24.com/
Should be an image backdrop, a 1,1 youtube video player (unviewable) to play background music. The music is in a playlist. jQuery gets the name of the current video in the playlist and writes it on screen, the song name should be ontop of the image where it says "Nightcore - Heroes"

Comment: which "the image"? The background in your css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `background-size: 100% 100%;` try changing this to `background-size: cover;` when I tried to change it in the chrome developer console it enlarged the picture.

Your code will become:

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/z6fgaW8.png");
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-size: cover;/* Note the change here */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div {
    color: #13eee6;
    font: 30px Roboto;
}
```

**For a decent explanation check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654996/what-is-the-difference-between-background-size-cover-and-background-size-100)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: inded it does, Thankyou very much for the fast reply!

Comment: I hope so too, don't forget that, if you think my answer is the correct answer, to mark my answer as the correct answer so other people with the same problem can quickly find the solution @GenaratedPixelz

Comment: Again, No problem @GenaratedPixelz

Comment: I cant tick it yet (5m), Whilst your here, how can I align the text to the bottom left corner? (http://darklegionrp.byethost24.com/)

Comment: @GenaratedPixelz try taking a look at the [CSS transform property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) and play around with it.

Comment: @GenaratedPixelz The `transform:translate()` property in particular

Comment: I just edited my CSS to: div {
    color: #13eee6;
    font: 30px Roboto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
} Ill put it in the post

Answer (score 1):

Your background-size is set to 100% 100%, while the body height is only 52px. That means the background image height will also only be 52px.

Set your background-size to:

```
background-size: 100%;
```