# Background image "cover" and "center" not working on android

Tags: css, responsive-design, background

I am having this problem, I have an image that I want to get full widht and height of a div showing always the center of the image, and it works perfectly on desktop browsers, even when I resize the window to a mobile size, but in Android browser it always shows the right side of the image and I cant achieve to make it work.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="main-content" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_field('imagen_portada')?>)">
```

And the CSS:

```
.main-content {
   width: 100%;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   min-height: 100vh;
}
```

To me it doen't make any sense that this is not working.

EDIT: BTW, if I use "background-position: left" the image get shrinked and if I use right the image just don't show at all, all of this in Chrome for Android, in desktop browser it all works just as it should.

Comment: I'd put a border on the containing div in order to inspect it. The dimensions may not be what you think.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? Depending on the version, Android is problematic with `background-size` properties. https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

Comment: @brianespinosa I am on the last version, Android 8 :/

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane  Did it, this is on desktop: https://imgur.com/qFVtgkN
And this on mobile: https://imgur.com/YDp6Uiq

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover` used in combination with `background-position: center` to zoom/scale the background images. For full-width/fit-to-screen background image, you can use `background-size: 100% 100%` or `background-size: 100vw 100vh`. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654996/what-is-the-difference-between-background-size-cover-and-background-size-100) to understand the difference between `cover` and `100%`?

```css
.main-content {
  background: url("//via.placeholder.com/1000/4B89DA/4B89DA") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I know the difference, and I want the exact result that cover provides :)

Comment: @BraisC I edited snippet to use `background-size: cover` option. Please run & test code again...

Comment: my problem is that "background-size: cover" works fine everywhere except in Chrome for Android, I want the "background-size: cover" behaviour in Chrome for Android.