# Footer image repeats or creates whitespace when browser windows scaled

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a webpage with a non-fixed footer, i.e. if you scroll to the bottom of the page, the footer is there.  It has a background-image which needs to scale for the browser size and work on IE11.  When the browser is maximized, the footer displays correctly, but when I resize it to smaller, the footer repeats.  So, I set:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

However, this causes the exact same problem, except the repeated portion is replace with whitespace.

How can I make it so that it doesn't repeat or show extra whitespace when the footer image is forced to scale from the browser resize?

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("../image.png");
    height: 190px;
    background-size: 100%; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

<div class="footer">
        FOOTER
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the background-size to 100%, set it to contain or cover:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("../image.png");
    height: 190px;
    background-size: contain; /* 100% is cover */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

See also: [Resizing background images with background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Resizing_background_images) and [background-size-property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: I found that background-size: cover fixed it for me.  Contain gives the same issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654996/what-is-the-difference-between-background-size-cover-and-background-size-100